# Exclude specific controllers from sleuth / brave to trace

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

we are using brave api in our spring boot application. We are able to trace all controllers and services. But issue is we are getting traces in some controllers which we do not want to trace like health check controller. Is there any way to specify this in controller as by default it is tracing all controllers.
I have tried using

```
spring:
  application:
    name: abc
  sleuth:
    enabled: "true"
    reporter:
      enabled: "true"
    sampler:
      probability: "1.0"
    instrument:
      web:
        skipPattern: (^status* | ^Status* | *status*)
```

and

```
spring:
  application:
    name: abc
  sleuth:
    enabled: "true"
    reporter:
      enabled: "true"
    sampler:
      probability: "1.0"
    web:
        skipPattern: (^status* | ^Status* | *status*)
```

But it did not work. Status controller

```
@RestController
public class StatusController {

  @Autowired
  public StatusController() {

  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public Boolean status() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`*status*` is not a valid regex. Try just `/status`. You can check the https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/v2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/SleuthWebProperties.java#L34 for the default. Also, maybe it makes more sense to use the `additionalSkipPattern` property to append your custom values to existing ones.